# Starting my app after QR code has been scanned

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I realised an app that read QR code and display result in a modal (then, redirect on a WebView if result is an URL). It works well.
But now what I'd like to do is : When a QR code is scanned with the **camera of my device** (not my app), then it launch my app and display the result in my modal.

I used intent-filter to do this... And it works well too ! But the problem is that it launchs my app not only if a QR code has been scanned. It launchs my app, for example, when I click on a URL on my phone. And that's not the behavior that I want. I'd like that it starts my app only when a URL has been detected from a QR code. Is it possible ?

Here is my Manifest

```
 <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>


                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"/>
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to open your app just for QR code, you'll need to specify custom data schema for your app instead of http and https:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

    <data android:scheme="myCustomSchemeName"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Then QR codes with `myCustomSchemeName://openSomething?param=42` will open in your app.

Comment: Sure, but what I want is to open every URLs. Thanks for your help